# Configure Azure Batch pools within a virtual network with Batch-Shipyard

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-batch

I am building a HPC cloud with Azure and [Batch-Shipyard](https://github.com/Azure/batch-shipyard), I was able to setup everyting quite quickly with the [documentation](http://batch-shipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but now I want to isolate all resources (especially VMs and storage account) into a private Virtual Network.
I read and follow the Batch-Shipyard documentation for that [here](http://batch-shipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/64-batch-shipyard-byovnet/) and [here](http://batch-shipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/11-batch-shipyard-configuration-credentials/#details) but I am facing the following error when I try to create the pool:

> azure.batch.models.batch_error.BatchErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Server failed to authorize the request.'

I'd like to use the service principal authentication so I setup my *'credentials.yaml'* configuration file like this:

```
credentials:
    batch:
        aad:
            directory_id: ***
            application_id: ***
            auth_key: ***
        account_service_url: https://my-batch-account.location.batch.azure.com
    storage:
        my-storage:
            account: my-storage
            account_key: ***
            endpoint: core.windows.net
    docker_registry:
        my-registry:
            username: me
            password: ***
```

Pool configuration file is mentioning the correct *'arm_subnet_id'* value for *'virtual_network'* key.
And application that refers to *'application_id'/'auth_key'* has been registered to the Azure Active Directory with VM Contributor role as mentioned in the documentation above.

Would you have any recommendations to me in order to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ensured that the subscription id and region for the batch account and the virtual network are identical?

Comment: yes, Batch Account and Virtual Network both belong to the same Subscription ID and Region

Comment: @fpark I found the missing configuration: the application was not contributor to the related Batch account. Now I can create a pool but the created VM ends up with the following state: **unusable**
Do you think it is related to the virtual network configuration?

Comment: Does your virtual network have any network security rules applied to it? If so, make sure the Batch VMs only spin up in their own subnet and follow the recommendations in [this guide](http://batch-shipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/64-batch-shipyard-byovnet/) under `Network Security`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I've been busy with other things. I tried with both:
 - no NSG
 - NSG configured with the guide you recommended
in both ways I am ending up with unusable VMs unfotunately.
I submitted a more detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678561/azure-batch-shipyard-create-vms-inside-a-vnet-unusable-status)