# Azure Batch-Shipyard: create VMs inside a VNET, unusable status

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-batch

I am having issues using [Azure Batch-Shipyard](https://github.com/Azure/batch-shipyard) to create a set of VMs inside a VNET.

Here is my configuration:

- Storage account (`mystorage`) allows only access from `myvnet/mysubnet`: [storage and VNET configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB4Yt.jpg)
- Batch account creates VMs inside this exact same VNET `myvnet/mysubnet` (using `arm_subnet_id`)
- VNET `myvnet/mysubnet` is associated to Network Security Groups that allows TCP traffic on ports 29876-29877 from any source to any destination as detailed [in Batch-Shipyard documentation](http://batch-shipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/64-batch-shipyard-byovnet/): [NSG rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xed7s.jpg)

Unfortunately, all VMs that are created with this configuration are still in `unusable` state, even if they get a [correct IP adress from `myvnet/mysubnet`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u56ul.jpg)

I also tried many other configuration but nothing is working yet:

- remove VNET configuration from Batch-Shipyard configuration: VM starts bu start task fails since VM is not inside the VNET and Storage account is inside the VNET
- remove NSG associated to `myvnet/mysubnet`: same `unusable` state

Did a miss something in the Azure configuration?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would start with a blank slate and try process of elimination. Do not have VNet subnet access on the storage account or any NSGs associated with the subnet. If this doesn't succeed, then something else, more basic, is wrong. Now add just the NSG subnet rule (keep in mind that you don't need to add an NSG unless you need to apply other security rules to that subnet. Batch automatically creates an NSG on all network interfaces). If that works, then add the VNet subnet access.

Comment: @fpark As you recommended, I created a new independant VNET **from scratch** and used it to create a new pool and it worked!  
Then I added NSG rules (with Azure Batch ports configuration) and restrict Azure Storage to this VNET and it also worked very well!  
So now I am trying to understand what would be root issue when I use a previously defined VNET, here are some thoughts:  
- could a `virtual network gateway` (used to connect to on-premise site) cause this issue?
- could `custom DNS servers` cause this issue?
- could `address space` associated to VNET cause this issue?

Comment: If you're force tunneling your traffic back to on-premises, then you need to [set up UDRs for Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-virtual-network#user-defined-routes-for-forced-tunneling). Let me know if this fixes your issue, then I can migrate this comment to the answer.

Comment: @fpark thanks for this very interesting link! I'll ask for the changes and let you know if the issue gets fixed soon.

Comment: @fpark After multiple verification, it looks like no force tunneling has been enabled. So the only solution to make it work was to create a new VNET with a dedicated subnet unfortunatelly. Thanks for your precious help!